# JFreeChart: add custom string ticks on XYLineChart's axis

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart

My app is generating heavy XYLineCharts (> 180k data points) using JFreeChart.

Each datapoint has a sequential number (from 1 to 185000) that is used for the X-axis ticks values (integer values, with auto-range):

```
plot.getDomainAxis().setStandardTickUnits(NumberAxis.createIntegerTickUnits());
```

So far it works great. Difficulty is now to add a X-axis tick with a custom value as I would like to add a X-axis label for the first and the last datapoint shown (I would like to show the first and the last datapoint production date - they are already sorted by chronologically).

I spend a couple of hours searching: it seems that it is definitely not supported by JFreeChart. I also didn't find any hack for this (e.g. annotations can only be placed on the plot).

Any pointer / idea on how to solve this would be greatly appreciated !

Thomas

PS: chart can zoom-in / zoom-out, hence the custom ticks need to be updated accordingly.

PS2: using Category axis doesn't seem to be a solution as it doesn't automatically change the ticks range (I think)

Answer (score 2):

You could consider using a `NumberFormatOverride`

```
Calendar startDate = Calendar.getInstance();
final String firstDataPointProductionDate = startDate.getTime().toString();
startDate.add(Calendar.DATE, 10);
final String latDataPointProductionDate = startDate.getTime().toString();
axis.setNumberFormatOverride(new NumberFormat(){

    @Override
    public StringBuffer format(double number, StringBuffer toAppendTo, FieldPosition pos) {
        if (number > 0 )
            return new StringBuffer(firstDataPointProductionDate);
        else if ( number < 185000 )
            return new StringBuffer(latDataPointProductionDate);
        else 
            return new StringBuffer(String.format("%9.0f", number));
        }

    @Override
    public StringBuffer format(long number, StringBuffer toAppendTo, FieldPosition pos) {
        return new StringBuffer(String.format("%s", number));
    }

    @Override
    public Number parse(String source, ParsePosition parsePosition) {
        return null;
    }
});
```

You can format the date as required.